# The quickest way to solve a quadratic equation with imaginary solution

Tags: quadratics

I had an exam question for solving an equation with imaginary roots:
$$
m^2-3m+6=0
$$
Obviously this yields imaginary roots. What's the quickest way to find the solution?

Comment: What would the solution look like?

Comment: Oh okay. Could you write it as an answer so I can mark it?

Comment: Good you have to marked his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the quadratic formula could really simplify things 
$$\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
for the general quadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$

Going like this the answer to your question is
$$\frac{3 \pm \sqrt{-15}}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

As we can see its not possible to factorise given equation. So using quadratic formula one can solve easily.

$$\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

Also one can solve it using completing the square method.

Answer (score 1):

We can also solve this using [Completing the Square](http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/maths/algebra/quadequationshirev2.shtml), as metioned by [Kanwaljit Singh](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2197795/401264)

*(Side note: I think quadratic formula is faster, I just wanted to provide an alternative method. This can also be easier if we are doing this by hand and have a large constant value and a small $x$ coefficient as we only need to divide the (small) $x$ coeff. by $2$ and square it, we don't have to multiply the (large) constant by the $x^2$ coefficient)*

We have $$m^2−3m+6=0$$

First we look at the coefficient of $m$, which is $-3$

We divide this by two and sqaure to get $$\left(\frac{-3}{2}\right)^2=-\frac 94$$

We can then rewrite the equation as \begin{align}m^2-3m+6&=0\\
\left(m-\frac 32\right)^2-\left(\frac32\right)^2+6&=0\tag{$\dagger$}\\
\left(m-\frac 32\right)^2-\frac94+6&=0\\
\left(m-\frac32\right)^2+\frac{15}{4}&=0
\end{align}

We can now solve this for $m$:

\begin{align}\left(m-\frac32\right)^2+\frac{15}{4}&=0\\
\left(m-\frac32\right)^2&=-\frac{15}{4}\\
m-\frac 32&=\pm \sqrt{-\frac{15}{4}}\\
m&=\frac 32 \pm \sqrt{\frac{-15}{4}}\\
m&=\frac 32 \pm \frac{\sqrt{-15}}{\sqrt{4}}\\
m&=\frac 32 \pm \frac{\sqrt{-15}}{2}\\
m&= \frac{3\pm\sqrt{-15}}{2}
\end{align}

---

Proof that $(\dagger)$ is correct:

\begin{align}\left(m-\frac 32\right)^2-\left(\frac32\right)^2+6&=\left(m-\frac32\right)\left(m-\frac32\right)-\left(\frac32\right)^2+6\\
&= \left(m^2-\frac32m-\frac32m+\left(\frac32\right)^2\right)-\left(\frac32\right)^2+6\\
&= \left(m^2-2\left(\frac32m\right)+\left(\frac32\right)^2\right)-\left(\frac32\right)^2+6\\
&= \left(m^2-3m+\left(\frac32\right)^2\right)-\left(\frac32\right)^2+6\\
&= m^2-3m+\left(\left(\frac32\right)^2-\left(\frac32\right)^2\right)+6\\
&= m^2-3m+6\end{align}